# Grails jms remote listener not working

Tags: grails, jms

I'm a beginner at grails and jms, and i was trying to do a simple message listener of messages coming from glassfish.

my grails-app/spring/resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    myQueueFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {
         targetConnectionFactory = { ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf ->
             brokerURL = 'tcp://localhost:7676'
    }
}
```

grails-app/Config.groovy

```
jms {
     containers {
          standard {
               autoStartup = true
               connectionFactoryBean = "myQueueFactory"
          }
     }
}
```

MyService.groovy

```
class MyService {
    static exposes = ['jms']
    static destination = 'myQueue'

    def onMessage(msg) {
         println msg
    }

}
```

But when i send a message, nothings happens! There's something wrong? 
Both glassfish and grails app are running in the same localhost.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you look at http://gpc.github.io/grails-jms/docs/manual/index.html?

Do you have ActiveMQ setup and running?

How would `static destination = 'myQueue'` make the jump to use 'myQueueFactory'?

Comment: What i was trying to do is connect to the connection factory in glassfish that was called myQueueFactory, there has a myQueue, i thought that there could make the glue. But i actually quit this plugin and start using the rabbitmq, since this plugin seems not be updateded have long time, but thanks for the answer anyway!